# Changing a line in multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have many files, from `file0` to `file3100`. I want to add `###` for one line in each file.

The line

```
Generated by trjconv : PTEG1 t= 8100.00000
```

should be

```
###Generated by trjconv : PTEG1 t= 8100.00000
```

The time (`t`) in each file is different. How can I add `###` to each file in once and the time (`t`) is still same in each file as before adding?

Here is what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

# loop all inp files in the current dir
for frameFile in frame*.inp; do
    sed -i -r -e 's/Generated by trjconv : pteg-1 t=.+/###Generated by trjconv : pteg-1 t=.+/g' ${frameFile}
fi
done
```

Comment: update your question with input lines from several files

Comment: this is line before: 
Generated by trjconv : PTEG1 t= 900.00000                                       
harmon , this is what it should be : # # # Generated by trjconv : PTEG1 t= 900.00000                                       
harmon

Comment: the problem is that you need to compare all files on `t`(time) equality beforehand

Comment: yes, that the time doesn't change time in each files.

Comment: i have this script, but it does't work                                             #!/bin/bash     


# loop all inp files in the current dir 
for frameFile in frame*.inp
do
    
    sed -i -r -e 's/Generated by trjconv : pteg-1 t=.+/###Generated by trjconv : pteg-1 t=.+/g' ${frameFile}
   
    fi
done

Comment: I've added the script you mentioned in your comment. Please [edit] your question instead of posting essential information in comments. If I got it right, it looks like you have an unneeded `fi`. You should describe what you mean by "it doesn't work". What happens? What do you expect should happen instead?

Comment: thank you, it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple perl one liner does the job:

```
perl -pi -e 's/Generated by trjconv : PTEG1 t=/###$&/' file*
```

This will replace `Generated by trjconv : PTEG1 t=` with `###Generated by trjconv : PTEG1 t=` within all files that have names begining with `file`